# Submit button mapped to Controller action without related View. Returning different view based on situation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

In MVC4, a controller named UserController contains an action ForgotPassword and a respective view is also created. This view contains one textbox and one submit button. On the submit of this button the email id should be verified, if not found in record, it should show a error message on the same view, else navigate to different view.
I have used Begin Form for mapping the submit button to a new action VerifyEmailId in UserController. However I am stuck on passing the view based on the validity of the email id. Note that this action VerifyEmailId does not have any related view.

Please suggest the best way to do it.

View Code:

```
@model UIKendoLearning.Models.UserDetails
<h2>Forgot Retrieval</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ForgotPassword", "User"))
{
 <div id="PasswordRetrieval">
 @Html.Label("Please enter your registered email address: ")
 <input type="email" id="Email" value="@Model.Email" name="Email" placeholder="e.g.      myname@example.net" />
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
 <br />
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Generate New Password" />
 </div>
}
```

Controller Code:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /User/

    public ActionResult ForgotPassword()
    {
        return View(new UserDetails());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendNewPassword(UserDetails userInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            if (userInfo != null)
            {
                HttpClient server = new HttpClient();
                server.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("EmailId", userInfo.Email);
                HttpResponseMessage response = server.GetAsync("http://localhost/BankService/api/Account/ValidateUser").Result;
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Found)
                {                        
                    return RedirectToAction("ForgotPassword", "User");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Comment: you can use RedirectToAction()...show us code

Comment: Instead of re-invent the wheel and have to return view base on content validity, why don't you use [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model) to validate your email?

Comment: Nilesh - yes, I have already tried that, and it successfully navigates to the desired page. However what about the error message and how to show it?

Comment: just use if else condition...`if(Email is verified)return View() else RedirectToAction(...)`

Comment: Nilesh - firstly, this action VerfiyEmailId has no view linked to it.
secondly, still it would only redirect to the new page, what about the error message stating email id is not valid?

Comment: can you post your code...so it would be easy to solve

Comment: @Nilesh not sure how to add code...

Comment: edit your question and paste your code for controller and view

Comment: @priyam check answer whether it is useful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar implementation, I suggest you don't need a new Action ValidateEmailID, but only a bool function that you can call from the ForgotPassword Post Action.

This could be the Controller code:

```
//
// GET: /User/ForgotPassword

[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ForgotPassword()
{
  return View();
}

//
// POST: /User/ForgotPassword

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ForgotPassword(String email)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    if (verifyEmailId(email))
    {
      // Do something, i.e. send email with proper instruction
      // Display a view to say action is done!
      return View("ConfirmReset");
      // Or redirect to another action:
      return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName");
    }
    else
    {
      // Add an error message
      ModelState.AddModelError("", "The email ID you submitted is unknown");
    }
  }
  // Redisplay the ForgotPassword View with error message, preserving the submitted email value
  ViewBag.email = email;
  return View();
}

private bool verifyEmailId(email) {
   // Your own code
   // return true if email is valid
}
```

And this could be the ForgotPassword View code:

```
<p>Please submit the email address to reset the password</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @Html.ValidationSummary()

  @Html.Label("email")
  @Html.Editor("email")

  <input type="submit" value="Reset Password" />
}
```

I hope this could be usefull for you.

Comment: the HttpPost solves the aim of maintaining 2 actions for same view...however how to maintain the error message of non-registered email id and show it in view if the email is not registered

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean, the error message is set by the ModelState.AddModelError call in the controller and displayed by the @Html.ValidationSummary() statement in the ForgotPassword View.

Comment: @priyam I saw your code, if you display the error message with the Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email) statement then set the error message like: ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "The email ID you submitted is unknown");
(just added the string key with the same name of the property to validate).
I hope this was what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

As @Doan Cuong wrote it is good solution to use content validity. For example, you have model for your view like this:

```
    class UserDetails
    {
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a proper email address")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        // property for displaying custom error message if validation failed
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        ...
    }
```

You have a form which calls action ForgetPassword. SendNewPassword should be renamed to ForgetPassword. And if you using try/catch it will be good if you display something if error occures. So, the controller code may look like this:

```
    class UserController
    {
        [NonAction]
        private bool VerifyEmail(string email)
        {
            // ... verify logic
        }

        public ActionResult ForgotPassword()
        {
            return View(new UserDetails());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ForgotPassword(UserDetails userInfo)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Here is userInfo.Email is a proper email address
                if(VerifyEmail(userInfo.Email)
                {
                    HttpClient server = new HttpClient();
                    server.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("EmailId", userInfo.Email);
                    HttpResponseMessage response = server.GetAsync("http://localhost/BankService/api/Account/ValidateUser").Result;
                    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Found)
                    {
                        // Here is error action ForgotPassword with param with field "error"                        
                        // return RedirectToAction("ForgotPassword", "User",new{error="notFound"});
                        return View("ForgotPassword", "User", new UserDetails { ErrorMessage = "Email not found" } );
                    }
                    // Here is all ok - go home
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            // Redisplay form with error messages
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

And modify the View code:

```
@model UIKendoLearning.Models.UserDetails

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<h2>Forgot Retrieval</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ForgotPassword", "User"))
{
    <div id="PasswordRetrieval">
    @Html.Label("Please enter your registered email address: ")
    <input type="email" id="Email" value="@Model.Email" name="Email" placeholder="..." />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
    @if(Model.ErrorMessage != null)
    {
        @* you can insert some good html *@
        <span>@Model.ErrorMessage</span>
    }
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Generate New Password" />
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your method

```
@model UIKendoLearning.Models.UserDetails
<h2>Forgot Retrieval</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ForgotPassword", "User"))
{
 <div id="PasswordRetrieval">
 @ViewBag.Error **// Your Error comes here**
 @Html.Label("Please enter your registered email address: ")
 <input type="email" id="Email" value="@Model.Email" name="Email" placeholder="e.g.      myname@example.net" />
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
 <br />
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Generate New Password" />
 </div>
}
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult ForgotPassword()
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["error"] != null) 
           ViewBag.Error = "Email Not Found";
        else
           ViewBag.Error = "";
        return View(new UserDetails());
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendNewPassword(UserDetails userInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            if (userInfo != null)
            {
                HttpClient server = new HttpClient();
                server.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("EmailId", userInfo.Email);
                HttpResponseMessage response = server.GetAsync("http://localhost/BankService/api/Account/ValidateUser").Result;
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Found)
                {                        
                    return RedirectToAction("ForgotPassword", "User",new{error="notFound"});
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```